# Dynamically changing receive buffer size for sockets

Tags: c#, sockets, buffer

i have varying lengths of byte arrays to send from  a windows desktop app to a windows service on a server on another PC.  I am using Sockets in C#.  What i was thinking of doing was working out the number of bytes to send and sending just that info to the server. The server app would adjust the receiving buffer size to accommodate the byte array being send from the client to that server. Is this a poor idea or a good one dynamically changing the receive buffer as the app progresses?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The role of receive side buffer size is to buffer the packets if the application reads data slower than the rate at which network can send. It also helps if the sender sends data in bursts. So, keeping it as a multiple of several MTUs (10/20) should be good enough. If I understood correctly, you are trying to communicate the entire data set (the length of the byte arrays) that you want to send and make the receive side buffer of the same size -- this is certainly not necessary and would be inefficient if the data that you want to send is too large! The reason it would be inefficient is because the OS has to allocate that much memory for the receive buffer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for such a concise reply.  It makes sense.  1 question though... you said 'keeping it as a multiple of several MTUs (10/20)'...   by the way you stated that i realise i should know what that means. (I have even Googled it).  But i do not :)  Is this related to the network adaptor or..?

Comment: Well, MTU refers to the maximum data in a frame that can be transmitted by the MAC layer. For Ethernet, it is typically 1500. Ofcourse, Ethernet adds its own 18 bytes on top of it as well. Sending data less than or equal to MTU means that the Ethernet can send it without splitting it into multiple frames; actually, IP layer does this and is called fragmentation. Fragmentation is bad since even if one fragment is dropped, the entire set of fragments needs to be retransmitted. So, MTU has an implicit but important consideration when it comes to sending packets.

Comment: Looks like, networks adapter do allow you to select the MTU size: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.prftungd%2Fdoc%2Fprftungd%2Fadapter_mtu_setting.htm

Comment: OK, so get the adaptor mtu property i am using to receive onto and set the buffer size to that?

Comment: Normally, you would not have to fiddle with MTU settings of the adapater.. Just see what the MTU is. In fact, you should be able to get SO_RCVBUF using socket get option API. If you want to be able to buffer more (due to application being slow, perhaps), then simply increase it by a factor using socket set option API.